# Plural or singular: (a) hundred years make (or makes) a century

Tags: grammatical-number

> 1. hundred years **make** a century
> 2. **a** hundred years **make** a century
> 3. **a** hundred years **makes** a century
> 4. hundred years **makes** a century

Having taken into account the entry hundred as to the links below, would you please tell me which one is correct? and, would you please show me a source that is authoritative in order to support your evidence?

[Common Mistakes in English](http://www.e4thai.com/e4e/images/pdf/E_errors/Common%20Mistakes%20in%20English%20with%20Exercises_189%20Pges.pdf) **NOTE** this is a huge PDF and may download to your computer

[How to Learn Flawless English](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ua2DibXhY1AC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=how%20to%20learn%20flawless%20eng%20hundred%20years%20make%20a%20century&source=bl&ots=oYmKXPDt-1&sig=L_tzxsc4w5GMSmhBd10iNgbBK94&hl=en&sa=X&ei=flVoVcLZBKau7gbV94LgBA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20learn%20flawless%20eng%20hundred%20years%20make%20a%20century&f=false) on Google Books.

Comment: Honestly, this sentence isn't very good. "A hundred years doesn't **make** a century"... it **is** a century... or, more accurately, "A century is comprised of one hundred years.".  Also, I don't think that "How to Learn Flawless English" is a good resource.

Comment: I mean, it may be fine if you're specifically trying to learn Indian English but many of the rules in it do not follow standards of English spoken in the US or in England.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot omit the article here, so sentences 1 and 4 are incorrect. The choice of whether you use the plural verb form or the singular is up to you. If you want to stress the fact that it is a hundred years, you use the plural. If you don't particularly want to stress the *hundred*, you use a singular verb form.